# Python 2.7: Cannot use subparsers with argparse on Solaris

Tags: python, solaris, argparse

I installed python2.7 on a Solaris server, and am working on a Python script using `argparse` to retrieve command line options.

Everything worked greate until I started using subparsers. The script fails giving this error:

`AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_subpasers'`

Here's a short copy of the script:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="myProg") 
    subparsers = parser.add_subpasers (title="actions", description="list of available actions", help="additional help")


    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",              \
                        action="store_const",           \
                        dest="VERBOSE",                 \
                        default=False,                  \
                        const=True,                     \
                        help="runs in verbose mode")

    parser.add_argument("-V", "--version",                      \
                        action="version",                       \
                        version="myProg 0.1",                   \
                        help="prints the version number")

    parser.add_argument("-z",                                               \
                        type = file,                                        \
                        required = True,                                    \
                        dest = "CONF_FILE",                                 \
                        help = "defines the configuration file")


    parser.add_argument("-f",                                               \
                        type = file,                                        \
                        required = True,                                    \
                        dest = "ENV_FILE",                                  \
                        help = "defines the env definition file")

    parser.add_argument("-e",                                                       \
                        dest = "target_env",                                        \
                        default = None,                                             \
                        help = "limits actions to a specific service. (Optional)")



    parser_launch = subparsers.add_parser ("launch", help = "launches the environment")
    parser_create = subparsers.add_parser ("create", help = "creates the environment")
    parser_create.add_argument ("-p", type = int, help = "passes the necessary parameters for creation")

    pymss_namespace = parser.parse_args()
```

Any idea why? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can remove the backslashes for line continuation - they are unneded.

Comment: They are unneeded because you're inside parenthesis (or brackets or braces), you only need them outside of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line 2: you wrote `parser.add_subpasers` instead of `parser.add_subparsers`...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a typo - it's `add_subparsers` not `add_subpasers` in line 3 of your script.